# Replace newlines in a Unicode string

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I am trying to replace newline characters in a unicode string and seem to be missing some magic codes.

My particular example is that I am working on AppEngine and trying to put titles from HTML pages into a `db.StringProperty()` in my model.

So I do something like:

```
link.title = unicode(page_title,"utf-8").replace('\n','').replace('\r','')
```

and I get:

```
Property title is not multi-line
```

Are there other codes I should be using for the replace?

Comment: Print the `repr()` of `page_title` and see which special characters it contains.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try `''.join(unicode(page_title, 'utf-8').splitlines())`. [`splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) should let the standard library take care of all the possible crazy Unicode line breaks, and then you just join them all back together with the empty string to get a single-line version.

Answer (score 12):

Python uses these characters for splitting in `unicode.splitlines()`:

- U+000A LINE FEED (\n)
- U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (\r)
- U+001C FILE SEPARATOR
- U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR
- U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR
- U+0085 NEXT LINE
- U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
- U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR

As Hank says, using `splitlines()` will let Python take care of all of the details for you, but if you need to do it manually, then this should be the complete list.

Comment: That is helpful. But looks like `splitlines()` did it for me.

Comment: No worries; I figured `splitlines()` was the right answer; This was just in case you really needed the list.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to print the `repr()` of the page_title that is seen to be multiline, but the obvious candidate would be `'\r'`.

Comment: I updated my example to include the carriage return (same result).